# Adding and Removing Angled Classes 6

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm developing an angled application where I want to add and remove a class according to my bool value.

I have this code in jquery, when I click on the button it adds or removes the active class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

in my angular component I have a function to take care of it

```
Exibir = true;
btnOcultar(){
   this.Exibir = !this.Exibir;
}
```

in my html I have the following line, even when my Displays has false value and active class gets added and the style does not change, how do I make this change?

```
<nav id="sidebar" [ngClass]="Exibe ? 'active' : ''">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution would be,

```
<nav id="sidebar" [class.active]="Exibe"> 

// if Exibe is true, active class will be added, if false, it will be removed.
```

Comment: Any may I know why?

Comment: In my active class my bg is red, and the normal color is black and when I remove the continuous color red. How do I know which classes have a component?

Comment: I don't get it. I just provided a solution about adding and removing class using binding.

Comment: I tested here in another way by creating a div and adding the class only with a bg, width and height and it also did not work

Comment: When you say it doesn't work. what is not working? my solution?

Comment: I cleaned the cache and now it worked, I do not know why. Thank you for your help